# Is it possible that for all $1 \leq i \leq n-1$ $\sum_{m=1, m\neq i}^n c_m a_m \leq k a_i (1-c_i)$

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

Let $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ be positive numbers and $c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n$ be positive numbers such that $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i= 1$. Let $0 < k \leq 1$.

Does there exist any choice of $a_i, c_i$ satisfying the above conditions so that for all $1 \leq i \leq n-1$ the following statement is true:
$$\sum_{m=1, m\neq i}^n c_m a_m \leq k a_i (1-c_i)$$

Answer (score 0):

Clue:

What will happen if $a_i \to 0$?

if $a_j$ are  positive, take$a_i$ small enough, but $a_m = 1$ otherwise

Comment: I made a mistake. $a_i$'s are all positive.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Can we disprove the statement for all choices of $a_i,c_i$ This means if it is true for one $1 \leq i \leq n-1$, then is there always a $1 \leq j \leq n-1, j \neq i$ such that it is not true.